# Incoming questions (migrated or otherwise)

Tags: discussion, questions

I suspect that few around here have noticed, but the new [Christianity.se](http://christianity.stackexchange.com) went into private beta last week, and into public beta today.

Some of the questions being asked there are specifically about Judaism and Jewish practice, and as such, are off-topic/closable there—but which might fit here.

Current example:

- Site question: [What portion of his income would a Jew following the sacrificial laws give?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1306/what-portion-of-his-income-would-a-jew-following-the-sacrificial-laws-give)
- Meta question: [Old/New Testament Jewish culture: On or Off topic?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291/old-new-testament-jewish-culture-on-or-off-topic)

That meta question asks if it would be okay to migrate this type of question here *with your permission* <sub>(sadly, there is no way for SE software to require permission; instead, a question would be migrated here, and the community could then choose to close it).</sub>

Keep in mind, though, that if Judaism-related questions are closed there as off-topic (i.e., not migrated), users may still choose to come here to ask instead—so don't be surprised if you see some new faces around.

---

The purpose of this meta question is to discuss how *this* community feels about questions being migrated, in *either* direction. Your thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. This is going to be interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think we're going to have to see how these cross-religious migrations pan out and deal with them, at least at first, on a case-by-case basis. In general, [we're](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316/non-jew-has-business-related-questions-about-judaismokay-here) pretty [tolerant](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32/what-are-some-mistakes-non-jewish-people-should-avoid-asking-questions-on-this-si) here about question content, as long as it's about Judaism and not other religions. So, I suspect that some migrations from Christianity.SE might need a bit of editing to fit in here, but that's not so bad.

The tithing question, in particular, could probably work here without any editing. The Christian-inspired opening is the motivation for the question, but the question is all about Jewish practice.

We have had a couple of questions here that probably would do better if migrated over to Christianity. It'll be nice to have that migration channel as a possible outlet. (I'm looking forward to History.SE opening up for the same reason.)