# As a Christian, am I welcome on this site?

Tags: discussion

I am an American Christian who loves the Jewish people and Israel.  I have no wish to proselytize or offend anyone.  What I am interested in, is learning about HaShem's chosen ones and their faith so mine may be enriched.

I have applied to similar sites and have been told I was unwelcome because I am an gentile and a Christian.  If my simple presence on this site makes anyone uncomfortable or is found to be offensive, I will dis-enroll for I've no wish to offend anyone.  I only seek enlightenment.

Comment: This is a virtual space. Strictly speaking, there is no "here" here. A person choosing to compose an appropriate question or to read the answers posted for the public has every right to do so.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316/non-jew-has-business-related-questions-about-judaism-okay-here, https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32/what-are-some-mistakes-non-jewish-people-should-avoid-when-asking-questions-on-t

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Sorry that this may have seemed as a strange first welcome to this site. Your first question gets closed as a duplicate. While one of the rules of this site closes questions comparing religions, personally, I find questions coming from non-Jews fascinating. As an Orthodox Jew, myself, I have to admit that sometimes my religious practice becomes so routine that I forget some of the reasons of hwy I do this. Occasionally, it takes a Gentile to ask a question to have me (re)explore things. I look forward to your questions, and, hopefully, answers as well.

Comment: I see you deleted your account, but please know that you are welcome!  (I hope you see this.)  Also, sorry for the delay; your question came when most of us were offline for Shabbat.