# How should a non-Jewish person use this site?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some mistakes non-Jewish people should avoid asking questions on this site?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32/what-are-some-mistakes-non-jewish-people-should-avoid-asking-questions-on-this-s)

I've asked an Old testament question on this site and got good response. Now I'm thinking that it would be a good resource to gain understanding of old testament passages.

Though I have a good understanding of how SE sites work in general, I don't know anything about the Jewish culture. This makes me wonder what would be the appropriate way of going around the site.

Are there any pointers you'd give to a new comer?

Comment: Thanks for the sensitivity that led you to ask this, but as it's been asked already I'm going to close this as a duplicate.