# Is this a suitable platform for non-Jews to ask questions about Judaism?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am not Jewish, but my curiosity was piqued about some aspects of Judaism after having political discussions elsewhere online with Orthodox Jews.

I am particularly interested by the way in which Judaism seems to be at once very open and forward-thinking, while still emphasizing a large number of ancient and complex laws and restrictions.

Is this a suitable forum for such questions? I'm guessing no, because they're not directly related to Jewish law. But I thought I'd ask :)

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya!  We welcome questions from everybody, Jews and non-Jews.  Check out the links in DoubleAA's answer; they should help.

Comment: Well, just wanted to say that I have asked a couple of questions here as well as a non-jew and always received excellent answers. (Though my questions might have been less abstract than what you seem to be wondering about)

Comment: try the chat if it's very non specific

Answer (score 15):

Provided you stay within our scope (see [our FAQ post](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1473/759)) anyone can ask questions here. If you are not familiar with Judaism, you may want to consider [the points raised here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32/759) in framing your question. We welcome questions from both beginners and experts. Try to write your questions to be motivated, clear and specific just like on any other Stack Exchange site.