# Would you mind me browsing your site?

Tags: discussion

I am not Jewish, but am interested to know more about it and have read some scriptures and writings. I have no intention of disrespect, so I politely ask your permission to browse and ask questions on things I might not understand fully.

Kind regards,
John.

Comment: Hi John! Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please feel free to browse the questions and ask any other question whose answer you can't find here! This question in particular, though, should probably be on the [Meta] site.

Comment: Hi and welcome (I'll leave the more formal welcome for others) -- just a note: permission isn't needed to read through the site, but questions are reserved for content building questions so this one will probably be deleted. That isn't to be taken as an insult just a way of keeping the questions on point.

Comment: Hi John, and welcome to Mi Yodeya!  All are welcome here.  This is a question about the *site*, rather than about Judaism, so I'm moving it to our [meta] site where we talk about the site.  You can follow the link in the notice that's about to appear under your question to find it there.

Comment: dupe? http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1330/759

Comment: @DoubleAA good find, but I don't think it's *quite* a dupe as that's more focused on asking.  I could go either way, but in the meantime I added a short answer here to address the browsing question.

Answer (score 16):

All are welcome to browse here.  It's a public site, so we wouldn't be able to stop you anyway. :-)

You are also welcome to [ask questions](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3521/472).  The community will help you with phrasing where needed, so don't be scared off by the jargon.  Here are [some things you might want to know](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32/472) to make things go more smoothly.

Comment: OK, that makes me feel more at ease, thank you. I've enjoyed reading some of the discussions on this site.. some very interesting perspectives on life too. Cheers.