# I updated Isaac Moses's query that shows posts missing the ALT text

Tags: discussion, editing

I used Isaac Moses' [request](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/lets-make-mi-yodeya-more-friendly-to-people-and-machines-that-cant-see-images) that everyone update posts missing image descriptions and [modified](https://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/query/1433141/posts-needing-image-descriptions-newest-first) it to show lastest posts first. See his post for more information to understand why these descriptions are important. I stumbled onto Mi Yodeya quite by accident, editing image descriptions, as I started learning T-SQL that the queries are written. There currently are less the 700.

I have since joined Mi Yodeya solely so any problems or questions of my edits can easily be tracked to me rather then being anonymously edited by 'Community'. I am not of Middle Eastern descent, I know no Hebrew and do not follow Judaism. I am a non-practicing Christian. I am open-minded and impartial about others' belief systems. I am aware this may be a conflict with people with stringent religious dictates and if anyone has concerns with this I ask forgiveness and will gladly remove myself from activity here.

Comment: Welcome G. Consider checking out https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32/759

Comment: Beyond this we are delighted you are here and welcome everyone ! Thanks for your contributions

Comment: Welcome. I wasn't really sure what you were doing, and so rejected some of your reviews.  I wasn't aware of this policy. My mistake, sorry.

Comment: @Harel13 Thank you. I don't take offense whether the reviewer actually understood why the edit was placed.